# Webpack (Create React App) "dynamic" js import at build time

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app

In a Create React App project (which uses Webpack internally) I would like to import locale related js files 'dynamically' at build time. More concretely the files are part of `moment/locale/*` dir and should be loaded based on values in an array variable e.g.:

`const locales = ['en', 'de']
locales.forEach ...
// Import from moment/locale/de`

I don't want to have it split to separate js files, nor loaded asynchronously.

I tried playing with `import()` and `require.contect` according to the Webpack [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-) but the locale was not picked by `moment` lib.

Dependencies:

`react-scripts (CRA): 1.0.17`

`moment: 2.17.1`